# how to refactor gui and business logic in C++

Tags: c++, user-interface, refactoring

I would like to refactor some GUI app, written in C++ and some GUI framework.

There are some dialog classes:

```
Class MyDialogX : public LibraryBaseDialog { };
Class MyDialogY : public LibraryBaseDialog { };
X, Y – some name, there are several such similar classes
```

This classes are used for gui stuff and also for some business logic – this violates SRP principle.

I would like to separate those two responsibilities and I’ve decided to create another class that will handle the business logic.

Now we have something like this:

```
Class MyDialogX : public LibraryBaseDialog
{
    BusinesLogic *pLogic;   // used to handle logic, called as a response to gui
    //    change, there is only one such object for all MyDialogX(Y) objects

    // ... some other code...

    // this method could be moved to constructor as well, only for 
    // short example here...
    void setLogic(BusinesLogic *p) { pLogic = p; }
}
```

Is this a good way to do such refactoring?

Maybe there are some better options?

Assumptions:
I do not want to make “businessLogic” object as a singleton.
I cannot change LibraryBaseDialog class.

This refactoring should be quite small, so I do not want to redesign whole system J

I could even go further and create some other class:

```
Class LogicHolder  // basic features related
{
    BusinesLogic *pLogic;  
}
```

And now MyDialogX will inherit also from this class:

```
Class MyDialogX : public LibraryBaseDialog, public LogocHolder
{ }
```

That way it will be easier to manage pLogic among several similar Dialog classes.

Comment: Have you considered just making a derived class from LibraryBaseDialog that has your BusinessLogic bit in (e.g. named LibraryBaseDialogWithBusinessLogic) and next derive MyDialogX and MyDialogY from this LibraryBaseDialogWithBusinessLogic?  I'd only adopt the approach you're saying if all the dialogs weren't from a common base class or is way too risky refactoring what's there.

Comment: two things: 
1. Your Business LogicHolder still needs to be initalized.

Comment: @sradforth that is a good point! I will check that. I did not want to use such code because I did not want to "change" way the MyDialogX inherits from LibraryBaseDialog. But this should not be a problem...

Comment: @jdisk right!, but I will do the initialization in some parent Dialog, so this will not be a problem for me.

Comment: (I HATE the 5 minute edit limit. I was going to write)
two things: 
1. Your Business LogicHolder still needs to be initalized.

2. In my opinion it es more elegant if you pass the BusinessLogic object in the constructor of MyDialogXY instead of using a seperate setter, That way your MyDialogXY will always be in a complete state; a separate setter can be forgotten, leaving your instance in an incomplete state.

What you are doing is basically Dependency Injection (to give you something to google) which is a nice approach to separate concerns and to make unit testing easier.

Comment: @jdisk again you are right! :) this setter is a bit ugly and I will move this to constructor so that only in the init part of app you can set this pointer to logic. I want to separate this to, as you mention, be able to test logic with some unit test. Thanks